# Travelling to Netherland via Frankfurt

Tags: netherlands

Going to Maastricht on student visa with Multi Schengen visa issued by Netherlands embassy in India. Can I take a flight to Frankfurt and from Frankfurt to Maastricht by Bus? Some people say that since this is first visit I must go to an airport in Netherlands. Immigration in Frankfurt will not permit to enter in Schengen area, as the my final destination is Maastricht Netherlands?

Comment: Just a small thing, but I think you mean 'Maastricht'?

Comment: "Some people" are wrong (especially if you have a type-D visa).  Who are they?